# divide the page horizontal and shows up new section without disturbing page content. and content auto arranged content from top to bottom

Tags: split, containers

example: if the content is going from top to bottom it will not go from behind or front of the new container. the text automatically comes down.

This new container comes at any
time. when come then split

see image for this

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5wRM.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide your code ?

Comment: see the above image and this code. what I need. 
as chat comes dynamically. 

https://jsfiddle.net/1gxusdrc/8/